# How do you check a row in a 2D char array for a specific element and then count how many of that element are in the row? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, rows, n-queens

This is an N Queens problem where the board has been given and you must use methods to check where the rows, the columns and diagonally. My method for checking the row is here:**It works if you were counting the Queens as a whole but I only want to check row by row, resetting the count and rowcount**.

```
private boolean oneQueenPerRow() //ensures that there is only 1 queen in each row
{
    int count = 0;
    int rowcount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
        //count  = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
        {
            //rowcount = 0;
            while (rowcount <= size-1)
            {
                if (board[i][j] == QUEEN)
                {
                    count++;
                    rowcount++;  
                }
                if (board[i][j] == BLANK)
                {
                    rowcount++;
                }
            }
            if (count != 1) // if size replaces 1 then it works, but counts Q's as a whole
            {
                return false;
            }             
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

The idea is that all the methods return true or false and then are called by final boolean method. If all are true than the board is a valid solution. If one is false, the board is not a valid solution. Here is a text file example I was given:

4
BQBB
BBBQ
QBBB
BBQB

(They should be stacked..)

I don't have enough knowledge about arrays and for loops to tell if this is going all the way through the whole file or just a row at a time, although trust me when I say I have exhausted all resources.

I have been working on this for days and I can't figure it out and connection with my Prof is spotty because of this virus! I desperately need help!

```
private boolean noDiagonalAttacks() //makes sure that Queens cannot attack diagonally
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
            {
                if (board[i][j] == QUEEN)
                {
                    if(this.toRight() == false || this.toLeft() == false)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean toRight()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
            {
                while (board[i][j] != board[i][size-1] || board[i][j] != board[size-1][j]) //add a count to this?
                {
                    if (board[i][j] == QUEEN)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }    
        } 
        return true;       
    }

    private boolean toLeft()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++)
            {
                while (board[i][j] != board[i][0] || board[i][j] != board[size-1][j])
                {
                    if (board[i][j] == QUEEN)
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }    
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: May I ask why you use (count < 1) || (count > 1) instead of (count != 1)?

Comment: Yes I thought of that since! I've changed it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it once ago and it worked, Hope it help you.

```java
private boolean oneQueenPerRow() {
    int foundQueens;
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        foundQueens = 0;//each loop is a checked row
        for (int j = 0; j < board.length; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == QUEEN)
                foundQueens++;
        }
        if (foundQueens > 1) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean oneQueenPerDiagonal() {
    int inLeftRight = 0;
    int inRightLeft = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (board[i][i] == QUEEN)
            inLeftRight++;
        if (board[i][board.length-i-1] == QUEEN)
            inRightLeft++;
    }
    return inLeftRight < 1 && inRightLeft < 1;
}
```

Comment: I understand putting 'foundQueens' in the first loop, but it seems go to wonky if the first array element it checks is not 'Q'..

Comment: My scanner for the file was incorrect. This works, thank you!

Comment: is it possible you did the Diagonal method for this as well I'm really stuck!!

Comment: Is the main diagonal and the opposite ? or all the diagonals in the board ?

Note: I want to help but if you do not get experience and get frustrated you can't learn, however I will.

Comment: I have been working on this all day due to a bug in my scanner and I thought I had it nearly figured out and then there was a a gaping logical hole and now i'm not sure how to proceed. When you say main diagonal and opposite do you mean 'down and to the left' and 'down and to the right'? Because if so, yes.

Comment: Wait a moment plz

Comment: I included the code I have now to the main question so you can see what I have currently. I initially tried without helper methods but there were issues when the Queen was at the last column and I was assuming that the total distance from the sides would be (size - 1) which isn't true if you're only heading in one direction.

Comment: Well, this is, hope it help you. Cheers

Comment: Thank you so much for you help I really really, appreciate it!